# Ordered collection with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, orm, sql-order-by

I have a some Container class like this:

```
@Entity
class Container {
     private Set<Item> itemsInternal;
     private ObservableSet<Item> items;
     private ObservableSet<Item> roItems;

     // ORM access by PROPERTY

     public Container() {
         setItemsInternal(new HashSet<>());
     }

     @Transient
     public ObservableSet<Item> getItems() {return roItems;}

     // private methods for ORM   

     @OneToMany(mappendBy = "parent")
     private Set<Item> getItemsInternal() {
          return itemsInternal;
     }

     private void setItemsInternal(Set<Item> value) {
         itemsInternal = value;
         items = FXCollection.observableSet(itemsInternal);
         roItems = FXCollection.unmodifiableObservableSet(items);
     }
}
```

As can see, the Container is an object-relational mapped and contains the set of items and exposes to the clients an unmodifiable ObservableSet of the items (also, the Container implements some other methods to working with Items, not shown here). After this I need an ordered Items by timestamp, somethig like this:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
 @OrderBy("created")
 Set<Item> items = new LinkedHashSet<Item>();
```

But in my current implementation shown before, the ORM sets the Set by a setter:

```
 private void setItemsInternal(Set<Item> value) {
     itemsInternal = value;
     items = FXCollection.observableSet(itemsInternal);
     roItems = FXCollection.unmodifiableObservableSet(items);
 }
```

and I haven't possibility to use LinkedHashSet as background Set.

How can I use LinkedHashSet as background set in this case? Will it be enough to set the required class in the constructor?

```
 public Container() {
         setItemsInternal(new LinkedHashSet<>());
 }
```

Or may be just replace a Set with a List (given that I want to have access to the items by an index)? Is here some drawbacks?

Comment: why not to sort right in method that returns ordered set? If you don't have >1000 objects in this set - there will be no performance problems.

Comment: normally this set have about from 1000 to 100k items, but may be it will need to extend to 10^6 elements... and seem it will requires a some sort of pagination in future...

Comment: well, you could try to fetch a set of items externally, without using ORM mapping or lazy loading, then just attach to this 'container' entity.  Will be a way to implement pagination in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Bauer, Java Persistence with Hibernate, Second Edition, p.143, I cite "*We don't recommend initializing collections late, in constructor or setter methods*". And further "*Hibernate wraps the collection you've already initialized on declaration of the filed, or sometimes replaces it, if it's not the right one*". Also in this book says, that if you need a set with stable interation order, you can use LinkedHashSet. But from javadoc of [PersistentSet](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSet.html) (a persistent wrapper for a Set) I see, that "*The underlying collection is a HashSet.*"

So, first, it is not fully clear for me, why it isn't recommended to initialize the collections in a constructor or a setter, but seems in shown case it is ok. Second, if a Set is marked by @OrderBy, then when retriving an entity Hibernate uses an LinkedHashSet as an underlying collection instead of HashSet. So, to get stable iteration order it is enough to mark the Set with an annotation @OrderBy and to use LinkedHashSet to first time initialization.

```
@Entity
class Container {
     private Set<Item> itemsInternal;
     private ObservableSet<Item> items;
     private ObservableSet<Item> roItems;

     // ORM access by PROPERTY

     public Container() {
        // first time collection initialization 
         setItemsInternal(new LinkedHashSet<>());
     }

     @Transient
     public ObservableSet<Item> getItems() {return roItems;}

     // private methods for ORM   

     @OneToMany(mappendBy = "parent")
     // order the data when querying the DB 
     // and use LinkedHashSet as underlying collection
     @OrderBy("created") 
     private Set<Item> getItemsInternal() {
          return itemsInternal;
     }

     private void setItemsInternal(Set<Item> value) {
         itemsInternal = value;
         items = FXCollection.observableSet(itemsInternal);
         roItems = FXCollection.unmodifiableObservableSet(items);
     }
}
```